# Schema.org for question and answer with two parts

Tags: seo, schema.org

I created a little question and answer website and I just learned about schema and would like to add it to my website to improve the SEO.

My current Q/A pages have a question and then below it is an answer that has 2 parts to it, each with a title. I then have an area for further notes on the answer (not all answers have notes).

This is my basic layout:

> **QUESTION GOES HERE**
>
> **ANSWER TITLE 1**
>
> First part of answer text goes here.
>
> **ANSWER TITLE 2**
>
> Second part of answer text goes here.
>
> **NOTES**
>
> Notes go here.

Please note that the answer is one answer with two parts, and not 2 answers. I would like to know if I can declare the title of each answer part in the schema, so for example if the answer title is "color" and the answer text is "blue", I want it to differentiate the title from the answer, something like "**Color** blue" If this is at all possible.

PS: if I'm totally on the wrong track, I'd appreciate if someone can steer me in the right direction as I'm new to this.

**UPDATE**

This is what I came up with, using a table. Not sure if this would be good SEO-wise or not:

```
<article typeof="schema:Answer">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <th>ANSWER TITLE 1</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>First part of answer text goes here.</td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>ANSWER TITLE 2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Second part of answer text goes here.</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</article>
```

Comment: 1) So you have everything working except for structuring the answer into two parts? If yes, can you include a minimal example of what you have? 2) Do you also want to do it if brings no SEO benefit?

Comment: @unor Thanks for your response. 1) I currently do not have anything, but I was planning on using the question/answer schema.org format. My main question is how to structure the 2 part answer. Would putting the answer in a <ul> <li> list help? 2) My goal with this is to try to get the question/answer knowledge graph panel on the Google pages that I rank highly on. And once I get that knowledge graph, I would like it to look good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google’s [Q&A page rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/qapage) doesn’t support any structure within an `Answer`. You have to provide the full text of the answer in the `text` property.

You can still convey a certain structure with Schema.org, but it won’t affect Google’s Q&A page rich result.

You could use the [`CreativeWork`](https://schema.org/CreativeWork) type to represent sections. The [`hasPart`](https://schema.org/hasPart) property allows to connect these sections to the `Answer`.

RDFa example:

```html
<article typeof="schema:Answer">

  <h2 property="schema:name">Whole answer title</h2>

  <div property="schema:text">

    <section property="schema:hasPart" typeof="schema:CreativeWork">
      <h3 property="schema:name">Answer section 1 title</h3>
      <p property="schema:text">First part</p>
    </section>

    <section property="schema:hasPart" typeof="schema:CreativeWork">
      <h3 property="schema:name">Answer section 2 title</h3>
      <p property="schema:text">Second part</p>
    </section>

  </div>

</article>
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Would this be better than making a table out of the answer? I am going to update my original question with what i came up with. Just curious which method will be better. Thanks!

Comment: @harvey: The markup you choose doesn’t affect the structured data (as long as you use URL elements for URL values), these are two different worlds so to say. So, while you might get the rich result with table markup, it’s -- from a semantic HTML perspective -- not a good choice, because this data isn’t a table, and `table` should only be used for tables.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I guess I have to look more into structured data. Thanks for paving the path for me!